# I have a job offer in the Netherlands. Can I bring my wife and can she work?

Tags: visa, working-visas, eu, netherlands, relocation

So, I have this very nice offer in the Netherlands (Work permit included). I will be there next week to negotiate, but I really want to know if it possible to take my wife with me and if she will also be able to work there? I am from Latin America.

Comment: EU isn't quite the right scale, it depends on the country and on your exact status. In the Netherlands, your wife should at least be able to come with you relatively easily. If you get a Blue Card there, she would also have the right to work without restriction. If you don't, I think she would need a special authorisation called a *tewerkstellingsvergunning* (not 100% whether that's also the case if you are a *kennismigrant*). If your salary allows it, I would really advise going for the Blue Card status.

Comment: Will totally check on the Blue Card thing, thanks!! :D

Comment: And of course if either you or your wife is an EU citizen by any chance, then things change drasticly

Comment: No, we are both from latin america, but the blue card thing sounds interesting. I guess I'll just have to wait until I get there, but now I can see a light :)

Comment: @Gala, wouldn't you like to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I wrote a comment because I thought that maybe someone with a bit more direct experience with the Netherlands could provide a full answer (the Blue Card might not be the only solution, it would be good to know what the rules are for the *kennismigrant* and other statuses). I will see if I can dig up more info about that but in the meantime it's good to let the question open and see if someone else can provide more details. You might want to rewrite the title to make it specific to the Netherlands, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed bring your wife and children - and I know this for a fact because I have colleagues who have done that, based on their own work permit.

But you should also check out the [official information](https://ind.nl/en/individuals/residence-wizard/family/marriage) on this matter at the [Dutch Immigration and Naturalization Service website](http://ind.nl).

Essentially, your wife has to apply for a residence permit, which you will sponsor. She has to meet a list of conditions which she is very likely to meet (e.g. actually married to you, valid travel document, no threat to public safety etc.), in which case she will most probably get the permit.

Your wife is likely to be able to work - but this depends on your own work status and the IND suggests there may be some kind of restrictions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. I think we'll make it :D